# MS SQL add max()-1 to qyery

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to add to the query max(o.Acct)-1 rows. I need to visualize the last two o.Acct rows. My query is currently showing only the max(o.Acct)

```
SELECT Max(o.Acct) AS [MaxAcct],o.ObjectID,o.Opertype
FROM Operations o
GROUP By o.ObjectID,o.Opertype
```

Comment: Is Max(o.Acct)-1 AS [MaxAcct minus one] is what you asking? Please describe your request more clearly.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the last two rows *(per group)*, you're better off using `ROW_NUMBER()` rather than `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ObjectID,
                                    Opertype
                           ORDER BY Acct DESC
                      )
                         AS sequence_id
  FROM
    Operations
)
  sortedOperations
WHERE
  sequence_id <= 2
ORDER BY
  ObjectID,
  Opertype,
  Acct
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last two of something, I'm thinking `order by` and `top`.  Something like this:

```
select top (2) o.*
from Operations o
order by o.acct desc;
```

Comment: Although unclear, I think the OP wants two rows per "ObjectID/Opertype", rather than just two rows.